# Want to open mail setup in iphone whenever user doesnt have implemented any mail account in mail

Tags: iphone, ipad, mfmailcomposer

I have implemented mail composer. But it opens mail composer whenever user had implemented mail account in iphone. My requirement is If user had not implemented mail accont , the mail setup should be opened.

Comment: What have you done so far? Provide some code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code...

```
      if ([mailClass canSendMail])
        {
            [self displayComposerSheet];
        }
        else
        {
               //open mail set up
            [self launchMailAppOnDevice];
        }

// Launches the Mail application on the device.
-(void)launchMailAppOnDevice
{
    NSString *recipients = @"mailto:first@example.com?cc=second@example.com,third@example.com&subject=Hello from California!";
    NSString *body = @"&body=It is raining in sunny California!";

    NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", recipients, body];
    email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];
}
```

Comment: @ Raj Subbiah - Thanks a lot.  You understand very well my requirement.